# Agile and UX design

Tags: agile, user-experience

Firstly, I'm aware there is a UX stackexchange, but I'm a UX designer trying to get more of a dev's perspective! How can the UX design activity work well with a team of developers and testers trying to work in an Agile way? There seems to be reluctance to do any (UX) design up front, and to only engage users after something has been built, rather than prototyping and testing with users before making production-quality code.

Comment: This question shouldn't be closed, it should be migrated. I just looked at the `agile` tag, and it explicitly declares all questions about agile methodology to be off topic for SO, directing them to the Project Management site:  http://pm.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: For those who are wondering, the "UX stackexchange" site is https://ux.stackexchange.com/ .

Answer (score 3):

The basic theory behind agile is that there should be close collaboration between the development team and the customer throughout the development cycle, and that the team has all of the skills needed to succeed.

In your case, the UX designer skillset should be represented on the team, and conversations with the customer about UX concerns should take place alongside conversations about functionality.

So, the explicit answer to "How can the UX design activity work well with a team of developers and testers trying to work in an Agile way?" is "In an agile way, of course!" You need to work on the same stories as the developers. Don't try to create a UX design all at once. Let it emerge over time as the stories are developed, just like the functionality. As the developers are working with the customer to understand the functionality of each story, you need to be present and discussing UX concepts. Functionality and UX should evolve together, so the developers always know both what the software should do and how it should look and feel to the user.

The developers have learned that big design up front is a bad thing; the same goes for UX.

Answer (score 2):

A key aspect of Agile is responding to change over following a plan.

Creating a detailed UX design up front works brilliantly as long as the requirements are unchanging and there are no technical problems encountered that require changes to be made. Agile is all about handling these kinds of changes.

The best way for a UX designer to work in an Agile way is to think of it as a 'just in time' process. What is the best way for you to produce good designs but to do the work at the latest possible time that is practical?

In this way if a change does occur (for example there is change in priorities and you have to quickly focus on other work) then you are best positioned to quickly adapt.

As you can probably tell this isn't a one-size-fits-all solution. Each team needs to explore how they fit design and developement together. With some teams they might have the designer pairing with the developer and work on the design and development at the same time. Other teams might do their designs a few weeks ahead and run them by the users so that they are approved and ready by the time development starts. There are no hard and fast rules here, it is about doing that which the team finds to be most effective.

It is all about discovering the best compromise between doing detailed up front preparation and being able to respond to late changes.

Answer (score 0):

You should try faster methods, as paper wireframing or balsamiq mockups which gives you a very good idea of what the system will look like, so you can test with real users and you are able to make an 'on time' delivery between sprints.

It is very important to discover what the user needs,or to be more accurate to see if they get the idea of your development before It's built.